# Windows Hosts файл как указать не домен а ip

Tags: windows, ip, hosts

Всем доброго времени суток! Можно ли в файле hosts указать **не** домен по примеру:

```
localhost example.com
```

А такую запись:

```
localhost 123.12.12.21
```

?

Т.е. чтобы редирект был не с домена, а с ip адреса. И если нет, то что может помочь с этой задачей?

Comment: впн свой нужен и настроить его, чтобы он ip перенаправлял в другое место. Ну или прокси какой-то..

Comment: Т.е. фактически можно использовать тот же proxifier?